# Webapi GET should return ids or values

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Recently I started to design web api for our application. I found many good tips in [this book](https://pages.apigee.com/rs/apigee/images/api-design-ebook-2012-03.pdf) but I can't find answer to question about response content. Let's say I have following models

```
class Foo
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int BarId {get;set;}
}

class Bar
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

When user make request to get Foo should WebApi return `BarId` or `Name` from `Bar` model by `BarId`?

so result should be

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"foo",
  "barId":100
}
```

or

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"foo",
  "barName":"bar"
}
```

Possibly should it return both id and value? Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: This question is **primarily opinion-based**. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: The general practice is to send only Foo unless you've having a UI where the whole of the information is laid out. Otherwise, keeping the information as minimal as possible will increase your network throughput and also the UI response. If the user performs certain action where the rest of the information is needed it can be fetched through Ajax calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the UI, what they need to show.

Better send both barId and barname, so that all information is send in that api

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"foo",
  "barId":2,
  "barName":"bar"
}
```